# How to add an anchor point/node in Figma?

Tags: vector, anchor-point, figma

How do I add an anchor point to an existing vector shape in Figma? Is this possible, like in sketch? Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course thats possible:

0. Ensure 'Snap to Geometry' is checked in Figma preferences (otherwise it is very difficult to precisely hover over the path to add the point).
1. Make sure you have nothing selected on the canvas and the selected tool is the Move-tool (Shortcut: <kbd>V</kbd>).
2. Make a double click on the existing vector shape to get into the vector editor mode.
3. Select the Pen-tool from the toolbar (Shortcut: <kbd>P</kbd>).
4. Hover over the path of the vector shape where you want to add the anchor point, until a little `+` sign appears next to the cursor.
5. Then click on the path to add the new anchor point.
6. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to abort the drawing of a line from the newly added anchor point.
7. You can now switch back to the Move-tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) to select and transform the anchor point.

For better understanding I made a short screencast of the actions:

[image: Screencast of how to add an anchor point to a vector shape in figma]

Comment: My question was how to add a node to an existing shape not make a new one

Comment: Agree with the OP. Didn't answer the question. How do you add an anchor point in the middle of a pre-existing line?

Comment: Ok, yes I agree that the video is misleading because it shows mostly how to append a path to an existing shape.
However the right information is in the last frame of the video, when the mouse hovers above the bottom path with a little `+` sign on it.
Will update the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer, please review if it answers your question now.

Comment: Haha, two years later (I don't use Figma often) I figured out my issue. If you have "Snap to Geometry" turned off, it's nearly impossible to hover pixel perfect over the line to add a point. Turn that on and it's easy.

Comment: OMG @CorayThan I just spent an hour with this exact same s**!"·$!"·!!

Comment: it pains me to say I'd rather have the Illustrator pen tool

Comment: @CorayThan Sorry, how do you append an anchor point in the middle of a line? Is there a keyboard shortcut for it?